# Is is possible to scope the jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scope the jquery object so I can overwrite added functions inside the scope with out changing the functions that are still in use everywhere else.

Here is an example of what I'm tying to do but it doesn't work as expected. Can anyone help?

```
$.fn.method = function(){
    alert("old method");
}

(function ($) {

   //I want to scope functions to jquery in here

   $.fn.method = function(){
       alert("new Method")
   }

   $("#MyId").method(); //should alert NEW method | WORKS CORRECTLY!

})(jQuery)

$("#MyId").method(); //should alert OLD method | DOES NOT WORK CORRECTLY
```

Comment: is there a requirement to keep the method signature exactly the same?

Comment: I think you could use the [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) functionality for this...

Comment: @Varinder unfortunately yes. I've written a large library of jquery functions that get included with the normal project but now I have to create plugin|addons to ship independently of the project and are expected to work on older code sets. only way to do this is include the updated functions that have the same name but work differently. Its too late to go back :(

Comment: @Mike... Just tried it. That only releases the $ object so something else can use it. I want to clone the $ or scope it

Comment: @Troublesum Yes. It means that you need to load jQuery twice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by simply copying everything into a new obj:

```
{
 const fakeJquery = (...args) => jQuery(...args);
 Object.assign(fakeJquery, jQuery);
 fakeJquery.fn = {};

 (function ($) {
   $.fn.method = function(){
     alert("new Method")
   }

   $("#MyId").method(); 

 })(fakeJquery)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to save the method in a variable and restore it after your done using "New method"

```
$.fn.method = function(){
    alert("old method");
};

(function ($) {

   //save method we are about to over write
   var x = $.fn.method;

   $.fn.method = function(){
       alert("new Method");
   };

   $("#MyId").method(); //should alert NEW method | WORKS CORRECTLY!

   //Restore method we over wrote
   $.fn.method = x;

})(jQuery);

$("#MyId").method(); //now alerts OLD method | WORKS CORRECTLY
```

Comment: by restoring the method at the end you undo the method at the beginning. This would be ok if it were a script but as soon as the next event inside the scope fires it will use the old method and not the new one

Comment: yes @Troublesum the "restore" must be the last thing in the current scope. Just like the replace must be the first thing in the scope.